# "Take their origins from" vs. "have their origins in"

Tags: expressions

Which one is correct:

> 1. Coffee plants take their origins from Brazil
> 2. Coffee plants have their origins in Brazil

Comment: Strike the _their_: "coffee plants have origins in Brazil." As a side note, you might have asked this question in the forum for [ell.SE], too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem.

Comment: @MετάEd Since there is only *one word* difference between the two sentences, isn't it obvious that he is asking which to use? And it can't be 'proof-reading' for the same reason. (I don't like the question either - but I don't think 'no research' & 'no explanation' are valid closure reasons *per se*.)

Comment: @TrevorD OP has given zero information about the specific issue he has with the two alternatives. Is the issue grammar? Logic? Idiom? The answer in each case is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is correct. You can either say "coffee has its origins in Brazil," or "coffee originated in Brazil," or "Brazil originated coffee." The first of these three is likely the most preferred though.

As a side note, coffee did not originate in Brazil, but Ethiopia.

Comment: Or, "coffee has origins in Brazil". I'm not sure I like your third option; that use of the verb _originated_ doesn't sound right when applied to flora, although it might work if we were talking about a particular coffee bean that was developed through careful and deliberate hybridization.

Comment: No, I definitely agree, the third option sounds off in this context. I assumed OP was a non-native speaker though and in other situations the conjugated form works quite well, so I didn't want to leave out that option.

Answer (score 2):

> Have their origins in Brazil

is okay, but even better would be:

> originate in Brazil

Comment: I agree with both suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to say, 'originate/originating in Brazil'; or further, 'They are a South American plant found in the country of Brazil'.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion completely.